# Getting tenthousands of warnings in a Unity Xcode project

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

I made an app in Unity and when I build for Iphone and open the generated folder in Xcode, I get tenthousands of warnings. The most I see at the top are "This function is not a prototype" on the file UnityRendering.h. Despite of all these warnings, the app builds and plays fine so far on IOS.

I found something on Google where someone said to add the line `#include <stdbool.h>` to the top of UnityRendering.h and UnityInterface.h. Just tried this and no effect at all.

I found it weird to get this many warnings, is it OK or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: From some quick reading around the internet, it seems normal to get warnings, you just ignore them.

Comment: @Kale_Surfer_Dude yeah that's the only thing I found by Googling as well. It just seems weird to get 20.000 warnings and that's no problem at all, haha. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to disable warnings for c++ source files. That worked for my project.